# Use Ant task from salesforce-ant.jar in gradle script

Tags: ant, gradle, task, build.gradle, build.xml

I have the following task definition in build.xml

```
<taskdef resource="com/salesforce/antlib.xml" uri="antlib:com.salesforce">
    <classpath>
        <pathelement location="${env.ANT_HOME}/lib/ant-salesforce.jar" />
    </classpath>
</taskdef>
```

I want to import its in gradle script.

I used following task definition in build.gradle

```
// ant-salesforce.jar in buil folder
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs '.'
    }
}
configurations {
    antSf
}
dependencies {
    antSf 'ant-salesforce.jar'
}
task antSfTest<< {
    ant.taskdef( resource:"com/salesforce/antlib.xml", 
        classpath: configurations.antSf.asPath, 
        uri: 'antlib:com.salesforce')
}
```

But this tasks not found in gradle script.

Anybody know how to import Ant taskDef in the gradle task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following link should be useful:

http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/how_do_i_use_ant_xmlns_in_gradle

http://groovy.codehaus.org/Using+Ant+Libraries+with+AntBuilder